# Mysterious LogCat message using SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, locking, surfaceview

I'm getting this message in the LogCat window:

> W/Surface: WARNING: Surface's mNativeObject (0xffffffffaebfa400) !=
>   mLockedObject (0xffffffffaeca2c00)

What does it means?

**UPDATE**
Thi is the code I use to lock/unlock the canvas

```
public void run() {
    long startTime;
    long drawTime;
    //milliseconds per frame
    long mspf = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
    while (mRun) {
        if (currentState != STATE_PAUSE) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //draw to our canvas
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if (c != null) {
                    drawAll(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            //make the frame rate consistent
            drawTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            if (drawTime <= mspf) {
                try {
                    sleep(mspf - drawTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            //have the thread wait to start again so we aren't doing busy work
            try {
                synchronized (mWaitLock) {
                    mWaitLock.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the code that generates the message [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-mr2-release/core/java/android/view/Surface.java#287).

It means that a native surface pointer changed between `lockCanvas()` and `unlockCanvasAndPost()`.  The message was added in [this change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ed55c8db1c0d47492423fc54f4b0dd5cd585e593), as part of fixing [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58385).  There's a fair bit of info in the bug report; it may give you some insight into what it is in your app that's causing the situation.

IIRC it should be harmless -- the code is just warning you that it detected what used to be a fatal condition.